# Ruby on Rails: Anemone and Redis issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, web-crawler, redis

I'm creating a webcrawler of sorts and when I use Anemone without storage to crawl a site it eventually crashes due to memory issues.

So I installed Redis, redis-rb, etc and changed my code to use the redis storage.. Now I get an error from rails and it does not finish crawling. It does connect to redis, as I can see activity when I monitor it, but it stops the crawl.

I did test redis and it works fine ...

Any ideas???

### Errors

> RuntimeError (-ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hgetall' command):
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ezmobius-redis-rb-0.1/lib/redis.rb:274:in
>   read_reply'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ezmobius-redis-rb-0.1/lib/redis.rb:198:inraw_call_command'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ezmobius-redis-rb-0.1/lib/redis.rb:196:in
>   map'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ezmobius-redis-rb-0.1/lib/redis.rb:196:inraw_call_command'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ezmobius-redis-rb-0.1/lib/redis.rb:161:in
>   call_command'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ezmobius-redis-rb-0.1/lib/redis.rb:151:inmethod_missing'
>   anemone (0.5.0) lib/anemone/storage/redis.rb:82:in rget' anemone
>   (0.5.0) lib/anemone/storage/redis.rb:41:ineach' anemone (0.5.0)
>   lib/anemone/storage/redis.rb:40:in each' anemone (0.5.0)
>   lib/anemone/storage/redis.rb:57:inkeys' anemone (0.5.0)
>   lib/anemone/storage/redis.rb:12:in initialize' anemone (0.5.0)
>   lib/anemone/storage.rb:30:innew' anemone (0.5.0)
>   lib/anemone/storage.rb:30:in Redis'
>   app/controllers/processpages_controller.rb:332:incrawlnewsite'

### Redis monitor results:

+1297028372.281985 "keys" "anemone:pages:*"

### versions/environment:

redis: tried version 2, and 2.0.4 - same p
roblem either version
rails. 2.3.8, ruby 1.8.7patch 174
os: centos 5
redis - default port 6379
hostgator vps / control panel x

### installed gems

anemone 0.5.0 and dependencies (noko etc..)
redis gem (2.1.1)
redis-name-space (0.8.0)

### code

require 'anemone'

require 'redis'

require 'redis-namespace'

Anemone.crawl(homepage) do |anemone|

anemone.storage = Anemone::Storage.Redis

anemone.on_every_page do |page|

...tons of code

end

### config/redis.yml

defaults: &defaults
host: localhost port: 6379

development:
<<: *defaults

test:
<<: *defaults

staging:
<<: *defaults

production:
<<: *defaults

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

```
RuntimeError (-ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hgetall' command):
```

Somewhere in your code, you are trying to call 'hgetall', but not passing the key or you are passing one too many parameters. Just check your code, and find where you call that command, and pass the correct # of parameters (1)

http://redis.io/commands/hgetall